# How to change the font formatting on an email sent through Outlook via Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, formatting

I have VBA code that uses Excel to send a number of emails through Outlook.

It inputs the name of each individual contact into the email body (Dear So-and-so), the company name/invoice number into the subject line (Company ABC Invoice 123), attaches a different file for each contact (Invoice 123.pdf), marks the message as high importance, requests a read receipt, sends on behalf of a secondary email account I use for invoices rather than my personal email account, BCCs to the secondary email,  and adds an email signature at the bottom with a picture.

Most of the code (if not all of it, actually) is from [this wonderful Ron de Bruin site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/mail.htm).

I pasted together a lot of code to get where I am and don't know how I managed to get it to work at all.

I tried numerous different "tags" in an attempt to change the font formatting.

I tried changing Outlook's template settings and taking the code out in hopes that it would input with the "Outlook default" font.

There are style tags in my code but they do not have much of an effect. It is set to Times New Roman Size 18.

The "Dear So-and-so" inputs as Times New Roman Size 12.
The email body inputs as Calibri 13.5.
My signature inputs as whatever I set it to in the signature setup.

I want it to all be the same font, size, color, etc.

```
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_1()
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim strbody As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

  Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

  If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then

      Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

      strbody = "<P STYLE='font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:18'>This is the message text for each message. This is all the same for each contact!</P>"

      On Error Resume Next

      With OutMail
       .Display
       .To = cell.Value
       .CC = ""
       .BCC = "MyCompanyEmail@company.com"
       .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
       .HTMLBody = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & strbody & .HTMLBody
       .Importance = 2
       .ReadReceiptRequested = True
       .SentOnBehalfOfName = """My Company Email Name"" <MyCompanyEmail@company.com>"

        For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                    .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next FileCell

         .Display
        End With

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing

    End If

Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:** Roland Shaw noticed that the font size did not have any clarifications as to what 18 was. 18pts? 18px? 18inches? So I changed the code to the following.

```
strbody = "<P STYLE='font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:18pt'>
```

This made the body of the text change formatting but it did not change the "Dear so-and-so" part of the email. Still hoping for some changes there.

**2nd Edit**: h4xpace suggested taking a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171418%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for some guidance. I already attempted to follow this guide before posting, but I could not get it to work. I went back and tried to just add what I THOUGHT was the relevant bits of code needed to change the body fonts. Additions and changes to code below:

```
 With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = cell.Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = "MyCompanyEmail@company.com"
    .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
    **.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML**
    .HTMLBody = **"<HTML><BODY><b>"**Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & strbody & .HTMLBody **</b></BODY></HTML>"**
    .Importance = 2
    .ReadReceiptRequested = True
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = """My Company Email Name"" <MyCompanyEmail@company.com>"
```

This did not work either.

I don't know enough about VBA to add the necessary pieces of code without altering what I already have.

**Final changes**

The code works as I initially intended it to now. The two main changes are to the following lines. On strbody I needed to add "pt" to the font-size. Also I needed to put the formatting information before any of the "message contents".

```
strbody = "<P STYLE='font-family:TimesNewRoman;font-size:12.5pt;color: rgb(31,73,125)'>This is the message text for each message. This is all the same for each contact!</P>"

.HTMLBody = "<P STYLE='font-family:TimesNewRoman;font-size:12.5pt;color: rgb(31,73,125)'>Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & strbody & .HTMLBody
```

Comment: @Kiquenet I did. The user below with 0 votes actually was leading me in the right direction. I had to add the formatting before the Input Text....  I changed .HTMLBody code to the following : `.HTMLBody = "<P STYLE='font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:18'>Hello " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & strbody & .HTMLBody`

Comment: @Chonchos you can vote to him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there,
You are creating your email body As

```
.HTMLbody = 'SomeText' + strbody(Formatting + MoreText)
```

Because the formatting section is part way through it only affects the text that follows it. Make `.HTMLBody` Start with your formatting information and everything that follows will pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that OP and I were trying to work around the same problem wich was to send a message with normal formatting and keep the signature via [ron debruin's method](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm).

I solved my problem by adding:

```
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & strbody & "</BODY></HTML>" & .HTMLBody
```

to the .OutMail object

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is:

```
.HTMLBody = strbody & TextLine1 & vbcrlf & strbody & TextLine2
```

i.e. put the formatting string before every line of text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the .BodyFormat property of the OutMail object to olFormatHTML.

See the example provided here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171418(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I tried this. I meant to include that in my post actually but forgot to.

It didn't work for me. I kept getting "expected expression end" errors.

Comment: That's odd, this works using Office 2007. You should be using a full HTML document for the body, however. Have you already tried that approach?
    "<HTML><H2>My HTML page.</H2><BODY>My body.</BODY></HTML>"

Comment: Let me put it back together and try to post the code in the comments here... maybe if you see what I'm doing you might be able to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm using Outlook/Excel 2010 by the way... if that makes a difference.

Comment: I started to try to append that code into what I already had... I realized that I don't know how to "make it work" with what is already existing. For example, I'm using "With OutMail" instead of "With ObjMail". I don't know enough about VBA to make the necessary changes to my existing code while keeping the formatting codes. :/

Comment: Also, I'm not using a full HTML document for the body. The body text is within the code as "strbody".

Comment: Have you seen this documentation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx